# How to pin topbar? The preference does not seem to be working

Tags: support, bug

I have the navigation option "Disable top bar stickiness" unchecked. It says

> When you check this box, the top bar will no longer be pinned to the top the page on Q&A sites.

However, I am not able to see the top bar pinned. Please see this screenshot. What am I doing wrong?

This is happening in Safari Version 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.7) Big Sur.

I can confirm that this does not happen on Edge or Chrome.

[image: Screenshot of preferences page with no sticky top bar.]

Comment: You have the setting set properly - I assume you've navigated to other pages. I've been using the setting since it was released and it's functioning as expected for me currently.

Comment: Ah, the good old Safari :) The header gets `_fixed` CSS class applied to it which adds `position: fixed` rule when the setting is unchecked. If the class is present on the element, then it is likely that the `position` rule acts finicky. It is known for having various issues on iOS (maybe someone with more experience in CSS can provide more details)